# Run a loop in bash on ubuntu, expected 1,2,3,...n but got {0..10}

Tags: bash

I have a script blah.sh on my ubuntu laptop:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {0..10};
 do echo $i;
done
```

In the directory with blah.sh I call it with:

```
sh blah.sh
```

Which outputs a single line:

```
{0..10}
```

Expected ten lines:

1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
10

How can I get my bash script to output as expected?

Comment: You are executing the script with `sh` which does not support brace expansion. Run `bash blah.sh` instead.

Comment: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).